# How to report issues on Tensorflow website?

Tags: tensorflow, cudnn

How can I report an issue on Tensorflow website? I am not talking about the API, but everything else, e.g. installation instructions and tutorials.

For instance, installation instructions indicate that Tensorflow for Python 3.5 and GPU requires CuDNN v5, but that is incorrect, as with CuDNN v5 it doesn't work, and it requires CuDNN v5.1 instead.

Thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please open an issue at the TensorFlow GitHub Issues page: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues